# .Net Core API with VUE Spa

Tags: .net, vue.js, .net-core, vuejs3, carter

I am trying to host a vue spa client within my api's wwwroot folder. I have set up build scripts to build the spa into the folder and that works well. I also use `app.UseSpa()` to proxy request in case of development. With my current configuration I am able to run the UI and navigate as expected however making calls with `fetch('/api/get/data')` only yields a 404 response or the html content of hte `index.html` file. I want to be able to make api calls and browse the UI at the same time with this hosted approach.

current Program.cs config using .net7 Minimal API approach with Carter library for endpoint mapping

```
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(opts =>
{
    opts.RootPath = "wwwroot/app";
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCarter();

....


app.UseCors(opts => { opts.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    return next();
});
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapCarter();
app.UseSpa(opts =>
{
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        opts.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:5173");
    }
});
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are under development environment:**

Check your Vue config file `vite.config.js`, look at this [document](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html).

For example:

```
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7121/',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5173,
    }
...
```

Make sure that the `proxy`'s `target` is actually pointing to your backend app.

**If production environment:**

The default released web api port is `5000`.

Use a reverse proxy server (such as [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/getting-started)) redirect to your web api:

```
example.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000
}
```

Comment: Totally was unsure about this path, I will give it a go and see if it is working as intended. I was thinking of a different approach before